# How to add users to an Azure DevOps organization based on membership in an Azure AD Group?

Tags: azure-devops

I want to add all members of an AAD group to my organization instead of adding them individually to the org.

This Microsoft docs page [Access with Azure Active Directory groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/manage-azure-active-directory-groups?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fsecurity-access-billing%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fsecurity-access-billing%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) indicates that I may use AAD groups, but no AAD groups show in the search results. Only ADO groups show in the results.

- My organization is connected to the AAD Tenant.
- I am a Global Admin in the connected AAD (although I am a Guest).
- I am the ADO organization owner.

I have tried entering the group name, the group's Object Id, and probably some other crazy stuff.
Is this not working because I am a Guest in the connected AD or what?  The page doesn't mention anything about guest limitations.

---

## Update 1: 6/2/2020:

An important [AAD setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/delegate-invitations#configure-b2b-external-collaboration-settings) I left out. This was configured prior to my original post. I thought that this would allow me to search for AAD groups as a Guest.

[image]

## Update 2: 6/3/2020

I converted myself into a member using the powershell commands.
[image]

1. I created a security group called "Test" in AAD
2. I created an ADO group called TestGroup in my org.
3. I tried to add the AAD Test group to TestGroup, but it can't find "Test"

[image]

Comment: I reported the issue here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1062064/azure-devops-cannot-add-a-aad-security-group-as-me.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, This is a Microsoft bug in either ADO or AAD.  I am not sure if Microsoft fixed something or if this workaround is required, but it worked for me and maybe it will help someone else.

**Workaround**:

1. Create a new Member identity in AAD.

   > **Note:** Maybe if you have an existing Member identity it would work as well, but I did not have one that I could try.
2. Add the new Member identity to the ADO Project Collections Administrators group.
3. Use the new Member identity to add AAD groups to an ADO group.

This new Member identity worked for me, and *Magically*, my original ID that I converted from Guest to Member is now able to find AAD users **and groups** as well.

Comment: Hi @successhawk That is great it worked out.  Thanks for sharing your solution. You can accept your answer.  Your original ID was not working previously maybe becaue it need to take a while to sync with Azure devops. when you change your user type to Member.

Comment: There was several days between that step 6/3 and the last 6/7.  I demoed it not working immediately prior to adding the new member.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Azure AD guests can't search in Azure AD. That's why you aren't finding users in your connected Azure AD to add to your organization.

If you're an Azure AD guest, do one of the following steps:

See detailed information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/faq-user-and-permissions-management?view=azure-devops&branch=users%2Fchcomley%2FAzureAD_updates_03_27#q-why-cant-i-find-members-from-my-connected-azure-ad-even-though-im-the-azure-ad-global-admin).

> Have another Azure DevOps admin, who isn't an Azure AD guest, manage the users in Azure DevOps for you. Members of the Project Collection Administrators group inside Azure DevOps can administer users.
>
> Have the Azure AD admin remove you from the connected Azure AD and readd you. The admin needs to make you an Azure AD member rather than a guest. See [Can Azure AD B2B users be added as members instead of guests?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/user-properties#can-azure-ad-b2b-users-be-added-as-members-instead-of-guests)
>
> Change the User Type of the Azure AD guest by using Azure AD PowerShell. We don't advise using the following process, but it works and allows the user to query Azure AD from Azure DevOps thereafter.

After your user type is changed to member. You can add the AAD groups to the groups of your ADO. See below steps:

Go to **Organization Settings** of your ADO--> **Permissions** under **Security**--> **Select the ADO groups** you want to add the AAD group to-->Click **Memerbers** tab -->Click **Add**--> **Type in the AAD group name** in the search box--> **Save**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you answer.  Please see my update, because I was aware of this "non-recommended" approach, but I thought that the AAD setting I configured would avoid this.  Also, I would like to know why it is not recommended.

Comment: I made myself a Member following the instructions, and it still did not work.  I tried adding an existing AAD group as a member to an existing ADO group and the Identity is not found.  I also created a new AAD security group called Test, and then I created a new ADO group called "TestGroup" and tried to add "Test" and it says identity not found.  This is not working at all.